# How to automate getting ZKTeco Access Control Logs

Tags: sdk, access-control, biometrics, zkteco

How can I automate getting the logs of ZKTeco access control devices (InBio160/260)? The documentation regarding the SDK is not understandable at all. From the GUI perspective, you select the devices, press Get logs, and select delete all logs after downloading them. This is something that is done constantly so I don't understand why there is not a built-in scheduler performing this task?

If anyone has set up a ZKTeco access control system or worked with their SDK, any help would be appreciated. Attached is the UI and the get logs button I want to automate.[image: Get Logs Button]

I need to sync data between different buildings but if the logs are not downloaded to the SQL Server a few times a day, the syncing program will not function properly.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an SDK wrapper in C#. [Code on github](https://github.com/MuaazH/ZKTeco_PULLSDK_Wrapper)

It contains all functions you may need, It can at least help you understand the SDK.

This is the function you want to call to get the log: [ReadTransactionLog](https://github.com/MuaazH/ZKTeco_PULLSDK_Wrapper/blob/3196ea83bff216f8f8382eeaab2b94df956be688/PullSDK_core/AccessPanel.cs#L300)

`Transaction[]? transactions = ReadTransactionLog(0); // 0 = all log, epoch time in seconds`